# SP2016, SSRS - The connection string is not valid

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, reporting-services

I installed SSRS 2016 instance on the SP2016 server.  Trying to create a Data Source (from the SharePoint page or Report Builder app) by selecting type: Microsoft SharePoint List and connection string of http://company/site/ (no "Data Source=").  The URL is fine and pulls up the site in the browser.  Creds are Windows Auth (Integrated).

When I "Test Connection" it always yields:

> The connection string is not valid. --->
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataExtensions.SharePointList.SPDPException:
>   The connection string is not valid.

I even tried adding _vti_bin/lists.asmx to the url with same results.  The SSRS logs have no new information.  Only previous informational messages.  It's acting as though the report builder is checking the "format" before hitting the SSRS Service.

Has anyone ran into this problem with SSRS 2016?

Comment: I have same error with you. I am using SSRS native mode not Sharepoint mode. How's your case?

Answer (score 0):

On my SharePoint 2016 server I had SSRS installed, but not the database engine...which if fine.  The actual database resided on the database server.  I followed the recommendations and updated the database server with the latest CUs.  However, I didn't update the SharePoint 2016 server with the database CU update.  Interesting that the SSRS log files didn't report any errors when trying to connect.

After I updated the SharePoint 2016 server with the DB CU updates, it connects fine.

Comment: I encountered exactly same error with you. Could you please mention which CU you were applying?